# Using a C library in my iphone app (ffmpeg)

Tags: iphone

I want to use the ffmpeg library (and maybe others) in my iPhone App.
But I have absolutly no idea how I can use the files that are in the downloaded zip, and get them to work in my XCode project.

I read something about .a files and frameworks. Maybe you can give me a description how to implement it?

Comment: There is a built-in, hardware accelerated video/audio codec library in iOS called AVFoundation. Unless you have extremely specific requirements, it should cover your needs and be fast.

Answer (score 0):

1st, you're not allowed to do anything with open-source on apple market : basically, any open-source library tainting your code (thus GPL, but also LGPL as dynamic linking is forbidden) will have your application removed if spotted. The VLC case (removed from app store) proved that GPL is not compatible for app store license (look for app store and gpl and google and you'll find hundreds of links)

Second, you have to transform the code you received (say source code) into a static library (a `.a` file). To do that, you need to compile it, here you have basically 3 solutions:

- put all the files into your xcode project and tweak until it works (thus not creating static library, directly merging the code with yours) : this seems the easiest, but will be a nightmare in terms of maintenance (each time you'll want to upgrade the statuc lib)
- compile externally, by hacking the makefile to use the correct compiler (the one in for ios, in iphone platform folder)
- add a subproject in your xcode project to compile the library

My advice goes for 2 (that's what I do with boost) but it's not a straight path

**EDIT** : don't forget that software video decoding will drain your battery and you might have poor performance

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any hacking; doesn't setting the CXX and LD environment variables before running 'configure' compile the library correctly?

Comment: depends on the library... I've sometimes had issue to make it find the correct lib and framework (same naming as system ones), everything is not perfectly jailed in ios world, so you can end up compiling for ios target while using native darwin headers.

Comment: You mention not being allowed by Apple, but what about the conforming with the terms of the open source license?  Isn't that important to you as well?

Comment: Apple license is not compatible withh GPL, as the case with VLC showed it. You can have a llok at http://www.tuaw.com/2011/01/09/the-gpl-the-app-store-and-you/ for example